# Was “God be with ye” grammatically correct at the time?

Tags: grammar, etymology

Several dictionaries I have consulted, as well as [another question here on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-goodbye), state that the origin of the word *goodbye* is “God be with ye”.

Shouldn’t it be “God be with **you**” or perhaps “God be with **thee**”, or did the preposition *with* really take the nominative?

Comment: As [this NGram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=God+be+with+ye%2CGod+be+with+you&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CGod%20be%20with%20ye%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGod%20be%20with%20you%3B%2Cc0), historically, *"God be with **ye**"* is vanishingly rare by comparison with ***...you***. OED says *goodbye* is essentially a contraction involving ***you*** (with ***ye*** as a bracketted alternative). But in speech it would usually be *unstressed*, so exactly how it was written would be largely irrelevant anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you are missing the point that *ye* also functioned as an oblique form in Middle and Modern English. Furthermore, you cannot trust N-Grams before 1800 in any event.

Comment: @tchrist: No need to go that far back - OED's own citations include [Dickens' *Old Curiosity Shop* 1841](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Heaven+be+with+ye+both%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) *‘Go thy ways with him, sir,’ cried the sexton, ‘and Heaven be **with ye** both!’*. Personally, I have no real interest in whether the usage was ever "grammatical" or not - I was simply making the point that *relatively speaking* it was never exactly "common".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an error to believe that *ye* was only used in the nominative or vocative; it wasn’t. The word *ye* was sometimes used as the object.  The OED says:

> **3**. Used as objective (accusative or dative) instead of *you* (in plural or singular sense).

And provides many citations, of which these are but a few of them:

> - 1594 Marlowe & Nashe *Dido* iv. iv, ― For this will Dido tye ye full of knots,··Ye shall no more offend the Carthage Queene.
> - 1613 Shaks. *Hen. VIII*, v. iii. 181 ― As I haue made ye one Lords, one remaine: So I grow stronger, you more Honour gaine.
> - 1667 Milton *P.L.* ii. 840, ― I··shall··bring ye to the place.
> - 1820 Byron *Mar. Fal.* v. i. 198 ― Was not the place of Doge sufficient for ye?
> - 1840 Dickens *Old C. Shop* lxxii, ― ‘Go thy ways with him, sir,’ cried the sexton, ‘and Heaven be with ye both!’
> - 1847 Halliwell *Dict*. (1889) I. p. xiv/1 ― I’d soon yarn sum munney, I warrant ye.

Notice how Marlowe even has it going both ways.

Comment: That crazy Kit!

Answer (score 0):

Objective you/ye was probably based on stress contrast like in Modern Dutch jij/je, Flemish gij/ge, or French toi/te. Sprachbund thing I guess.