# English greeting with religious connotation

Tags: greetings, religion

Since the English language has a number of idioms and phrases that involve references to religious figures (e.g., godspeed), I was wondering if
there an English equivalent of the German greeting

> Grüß Gott

which translates roughly as (see also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BC%C3%9F_Gott))

> May God greet you

or any other greeting that originates from a religious context.

Edit: despite its literal meaning, the German *Grüß Gott* is used quite freely, even if no reference to God is intended.

Comment: Like God bless you or Wish you God's love?

Comment: @Josh61 Exactly, but are those used as greetings?

Comment: Somewhat related (but not an answer): *goodbye* is an [old corruption of "God be with you"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-goodbye), but it has since completely lost any religious connotation. "Goodbye" -- from an etymological perspective -- is incredibly close to "May God greet you" (but, of course, is a farewell).

Comment: In English the tendency is to only invoke God's blessing (when it's done at all) on parting -- "God be with you" or "God bless" or such.

Comment: @HotLicks I see. But would a nonreligious person use such phrases?

Comment: Generally such phrases would only be used by someone who was openly religious.  (Though "goodbye", as noted, no longer has a religious connotation.)

Comment: It only really applies to *British* English, but... *"**Gor blimey!** Fancy meeting **you** here!"*. Plus of course there's *"Speak of the **Devil**! Nice to see you!"*

Answer (score 4):

Good day, good morning, good afternoon, good evening, good night

Per [this dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/good%20day%20?s=t),

> All these greetings represent an abbreviation of the now obsolete God give you a good day (afternoon, etc.) , which dates from about 1200.

Look under 'Idioms and Phrases'.

Answer (score 1):

Recently in America, there was a very temporary ban placed on uttering the greeting ***"Have a blessed day"*** at an Air Force base in Georgia. Several news outlets covered the story including Fox News; it seems that the phrase "Have a blessed day" was indeed used as a greeting to visitors and officers entering the base, rather than as a farewell.

[Here is the initial article](http://www.airforcetimes.com/story/military/2015/03/12/robins-personnel-to-stop-using-blessed-day-greeting/70225294/?from=global&sessionKey=&autologin=) about the ban on the greeting in the Air Force Times. And [here is the article](http://www.airforcetimes.com/story/military/2015/03/12/airmen-can-wish-visitors-at-robins-a-blessed-day-again/70236366/) announcing the reversal of the ban, published three hours later. In both, the phrase "Have a blessed day" is explicitly referred to as a greeting.

Comment: But that is not a common greeting anywhere except maybe by those few people in Georgia.

Comment: Hi Mitch, check the OP's question, they are seeking an English equivalent, not a common phrase. Also you might be interested to see that folks in Kentucky use the expression as well: http://www.fox19.com/story/25927380/have-a-blessed-day Thanks!

Comment: The OP is seeking something like "Gruess Gott". If he didn't want a common phrase, then a direct translation would be sufficient, and he said he doesn't want that. Yours is a reasonable answer, because more than one person uses it, but I am adding the nuance that it is not at all a common greeting like "Gruess Gott" is in southern Germany. "Have a blessed day" is a very modern deliberate construction. It's like saying "Enjoy your meal" corresponds directly to "Guten Appetit".

Comment: Nice nuance, I get it!

Comment: 'Bless you' after someone sneezes, though it doesn't correspond in meaning, corresponds to the other criteria: it is very common and few people think of it as having a religious connotation (and it uses the obvious 'bless').